# How to add a specific URL to each image and news in Facebook Comment Box Plugin

Tags: php, jquery, html, facebook

I am trying to configure Facebook Comment Box plugin for multiple images and news posts on my website. For this I have build an app on Facebook and generate plugin code as mentioned in the documentation.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=MY_APP_ID";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And comment box Mark up :

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://WEBSITE_URL/index.php?gallery_image=GALLERY_IMAGE_ID" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

The 'data-url' provided in the mark up is unique on the basis of image_id.

I want that whenever a person comments on an image, it must be specific to that image and the same comment should not be displayed on other images.(As it is happening right now)

I am sticking to it from last 2 days. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to point the comments plugin to an HTML document, not an image directly. That HTML document should contain the basic Open Graph meta data.

Comment: I have set the comments plugin to an HTML document and also using Open Graph meta tags in the HTML document that points to an image_url. But its still not displaying unique comments. What should I do now ?

Comment: Make sure you have `og:url` set correctly as well - individually for each individual URL. (Use FB debug tool to refresh cache, after you make changes.)